Changing lightning-card height

How do I set the lightning-card to a specific height ? I prefer not using  around to achieve it.
I've tried putting custom class inside but it doesn't work. Styling hook is not working as well since there are no defined slds class for it.
<lightning-card title="test" class="my-custom-card">


By default when you use the lightning-card CSS apply display: inline;. That's why when you apply your custom CSS for the height will not apply.
You can try setting the display to something other than inline and it will work.
HTML:
<lightning-card title="test" class="my-custom-card">
</lightning-card>

CSS:
.my-custom-card {
  display: block;
  height: 300px; 
}


Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work. Probably because of DOM encapsulation
